# Scale deformation when rotating imported FBX

Tags: modeling, export, import, transforms, .fbx

I've been working on this gun model and all was going well until I tried importing it into another blender save, I then realized that the imported FBX's parts deform when I rotate them, this does not happen in the .blend save of the model however. I have tried un-parenting all the children and then reattaching them and exporting it and re-importing it again but still whenever I rotate a child of the main weapon it deforms and stretches. No idea what's causing it, it's especially strange because it doesn't occur in the .blend save of the model but does if I import it into a blender save. Here are some screen shots for example.

Base Weapon:
[image: Normal Weapon]
Rotated Children:
[image: Normal Weapon, Rotations]
Rotated Children on same model, but reimported (Above):
[image: Reimported Weapon, Rotations]
Thanks, any help or suggestions would be appreciated, I'm stumped. <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you apply all rotation and scale to the children before parenting them, having weird scaling can produce those results.

You can do this by selecting the child in object mode and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and selecting "Rotation and Scale".

Comment: Hey, thanks that worked. I thought it might be to do with the scaling of the parent in relation to the children but couldn't think of how to fix it but that worked. :D